# MySQL - Nested set model: searching in nodes

Tags: sql, mysql, nested-sets

Let's just say I have tree in my table called "page":

```
Foo
  -- Bar 1
  -- Bar 2
      -- Bar 3
  -- Some foo
  -- Some value
Bar
  -- Bar 4
```

I want to search by node's name. For example "bar%". Excpected output should be:

```
Foo
  -- Bar 1
  -- Bar 2
     -- Bar 3
Bar
  -- Bar 4
```

I can't find solution to write right query in MySQL. Searching is not a problem - I don't know how to get a depth of a node in search results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  mc.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    page mp
        WHERE   mc.lft BETWEEN mp.lft AND mp.rgt
        ) AS depth
FROM    page mc
WHERE   mc.name LIKE 'bar%'
```

This query can be improved if you create your `(lft, rgt)`'s as a single field `sets LineString` and make a `SPATIAL INDEX` over this field:

```
SELECT  mc.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    page mp
        WHERE   MBRWIthin(Point(0, mc.lft), mp.sets)
        ) AS depth
FROM    page mc
WHERE   mc.name LIKE 'bar%'
```

See this article for more details:

- [**Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)